# JAVA вызов конструктора из другого. Как сделать вызов, если он должен быть первым?

Tags: java, объекты

Здравствуйте! Объясню суть проблемы:
есть класс, в котором 2 конструктора.

***Первый конструктор*** - по умолчанию, при его вызове нужно:

1. загрузить данные из файла, в объект Properties
2. из этого объекта вытянуть данные и дальше загрузить их в
       программу.

***Второй конструктор*** - с параметром Properties, при его вызове нужно:

1. из принимаемого объекта вытянуть
       данные и дальше загрузить в
       программу.

Из этого описания напрашивается следующий код:

```
public class Configuration {

public Configuration() {
    this.firstPort = new PortConfig();
    this.secondPort = new PortConfig();

    Properties pp = new Properties(); // в этот объект загружаем данные из файла
    try {
        File PropFile = new File(CONFIGURATION_FILENAME);
        if (!PropFile.exists()) {
            PropFile.createNewFile();
        }
        FileInputStream inPropFile = new FileInputStream(CONFIGURATION_FILENAME);
        pp.load(inPropFile);

// МОМЕНТ ИСТИНЫ.
        THIS(pp); // ВОТ ТУТ КОМПИЛЯТОР БУДЕТ РУГАТЬСЯ, ЧТО ЭТОТ ВЫЗОВ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ ПЕРВЫМ

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Configuration(Properties p) {

    this.setLogFileName(p.getProperty("logFileName"));
    this.setLogWidth(Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("logWidth")));

}
```

Comment: нече не понятно.. в чем проблема? напиши метод с нужным порядков вызовов и все...

Comment: проблема в том, что я использую метод setProperties. Хотелось бы обойтись 2вумя конструкторами, но это не получается, из за того, что вызов другого конструктора должен быть первым

Comment: ох, что-то у меня в вопросе все поехало, сейчас подправлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На вызовы одного конструктора из другого накладываются следующие ограничения:

> You can call one constructor from
> another in the same class, or call the
> super class, with the following
> restrictions:
>
> - It has to be the first line of code in the calling constructor.
> - It cannot have any explicit or implicit reference to this. So you cannot pass an inner class (even an anonymous one if it references any instance methods), or the result of a  non-static method call, as a parameter.

---

Для вашего случая решением может стать следующий рефакторинг:

```
public Configuration() {
    this(loadPropertiesFile(...));
}

private Properties loadPropertiesFile(...) {
    File propertiesFile = new File(...);
    // ...
}
```

Кстати говоря, вам стоит отдельно обратить внимание на подход к обработке исключений, поскольку решение вида *suppress and print stack trace* в конструкторе - это далеко не самый элегантный подход.

Comment: ООоо, т.е. все, что у меня было в конструкторе по умолчанию, Вы предлагаете вынести в отдельный метод?

Comment: возможно это идеальное решение, благодарствую!

Comment: **static** private Properties loadPropertiesFile(...)

Answer (score 1):

У Вас все правильно тогда.

```
class Configuration{
    Configuration(){
        Properties pp=loadProrertiesFromFile();
        loadProperties(pp);
    };
    Configuration(Properties prop){
        loadProperties(prop);
    };
    private void loadProperties(Properties pp){

    };
};
```

Ваш упрощенный код без лишнего. Чем он Вас смущает?

Comment: в данный момент у меня так и сделано, из обоих конструкторов вызывается функция, в точности как Вы написали выше. Меня смущает лишь то, что можно сделать то же самое, но используя лишь 2 конструктора, именно поэтому я и написал на сей портал :)